# Sitecore Upload Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to upload images on Sitecore 6.6 from Safari Browser .
It showing me : One or more files can't be uploaded. 
On other browers (Chrome,Firefox) works fine. 
I checked in the logs and I didn't find something to help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try modifying the following settings:

```
<setting name="Upload.Classic" value="true" />
```